# Doctrine's between function skipping the range start?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have a mapped object in Doctrine that, among other fields, has a *DateTime* one defined like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date")
 * @var \DateTime
 */
private $runDate;
```

Then I have this code, that should return all the objects between two *DateTime*s:

```
public function getBetweenDates(\DateTime $from, \DateTime $to) {


$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('e')
        ->from(\MyClass::class,'e')
        ->add('where', $qb->expr()->between(
            'e.runDate',
            ':from',
            ':to'
        )
    );

    $qb->addOrderBy('e.runDate', 'ASC');
    $qb->setParameters(array('from' => $from, 'to' => $to));
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

However, if, say, I persist objects for *2016-11-20T0:0:0*, *2016-11-21T0:0:0*, *2016-11-22T0:0:0*, *2016-11-23T0:0:0*, and I call the function with from=*2016-11-**20**T0:0:0* and to=*2016-11-**23**T0:0:0*, then I only get the objects for day 21, 22 and 23.

Is it the intended behavior or a bug in Doctrine?